# Split python list containing objects by object type

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I tried the following and it seems like its working. The question is this the pythonic way? My actual code is very complex with inheritance. I am trying to check and will update. Thanks

```
class A:
    def __repr__(self):
        return "A"

class B:
    def __repr__(self):
        return "B"

class C:
    def __repr__(self):
        return "C"

def split_by_type(object_list, obj_type):
    final, inter = [], []
    for obj in object_list:
        if isinstance(obj, obj_type):
            if inter:
                final.append(inter)
            inter = [obj]
        else:
            inter.append(obj)
    final.append(inter)
    return final
```

**Input**: `[A1, B1, C1, A2, B2, A3, C3, A4, B4, C4]`

**Output**: `[[A1, B1, C1], [A2, B2], [A3, C3], [A4, B4, C4]]`

```
object_list = [A(), B(), C(), A(), B(), A(), C(), A(), B(), C()]
print(split_by_type(object_list, A)) # ==> [[A, B, C], [A, B], [A, C], [A, B, C]]
```

Comment: If you want comments for how to improve code try: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I was asking this question as I had no solution. Then I thought asking without trying will be bad. Then I tried. I don't know if this will work at all. for sample code it is working. Thanks. I will move if nobody is interested.

Comment: This is ok for SO IMO

Comment: How would you handle class inheritance here? Or are you assuming that never happens

Comment: I never thought about that. I have not tried for my actual code but it contains inheritance. I need the code which works with inheritance.

Comment: why arent you using `groupby`? I dont understand the purpose of this code, it is not clear what you want to do or what you want suggestions on

Comment: your current approach is okay then i think

Comment: @NathanMcCoy what `key` function would you parse to `groupby`? (`lambda x: isinstance(x, obj_type))` does not work of course)

Comment: Seems like you are using `repr` anyways so `lambda o: repr(o)`, Might want to sort by same key.

Comment: @NathanMcCoy: see input and output part. If you have a working example plz answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` and `itertools.count`:

```
object_list = [A(), B(), C(), A(), B(), A(), C(), A(), B(), C()]

from itertools import groupby, count

c = count()
out = [[o[1] for o in g] for v, g in groupby(enumerate(object_list), lambda o: o[0]-[next(c), next(c)][-1] if isinstance(o[1], A) else o[0]-next(c))]

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[[A, B, C], [A, B], [A, C], [A, B, C]]
```

Comment: Thanks for understanding my question and helping.

Comment: One more question. How variable `o` from inner list `[o[1] for o in g]` is accessible outside? Is this because of side effect or it is normal behavior. I smell closure that I never understood.

Comment: @Rahul There's no closure. `groupby()` is returning two variables `v` -> the key used in grouping and iterator `g`. I'm simply iterating through `g` in list comprehension and taking second element from the tuple (note the `enumerate()` in the `groupby()`)

Comment: oh!. I see. I got confused because of reuse of variable `o` again in lambda. so `o` in `[o[1] for o in g]` is different from `lambda o: o[0] ...`. Right?

Comment: @Rahul Yes, they are different.

Comment: Why would you use this though? @Rahul 's original is certainly more readable